# My child Div Cannot scroll to the bottom

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner in HTML and CSS and I've encountered a problem.

I tried to look for some solutions, but I still cannot manage to fix my problem.

My child Div(child of the midtop div) cannot be scrolled to the bottom, which makes the last submit button invisible if I add more tables to it.

I'm not really sure what is the root cause of the problem.

The structure of my divs look like this:

> wrapper
>
> > header
> >
> > midtop
> >
> > > firstQ

Thanks in advance.

Here is the link to my code:

https://github.com/erictaur/Course-Query/blob/test-branch/InnoServ/Entry.html

https://github.com/erictaur/Course-Query/blob/test-branch/InnoServ/entrycss.css

Part of my code looks like this

```css
.wrapper {
  display: block;
}

#header {
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  left: 50%;
  top: 0%;
  display: block;
}

#midtop {
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  height: 600px;
  left: 50%;
  overflow: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

#firstQ {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="header"> #child1
    <p id="Welcome">Welcome!</p>
  </div> #end of header


  <div id="midtop"> #child2

    <div id="firstQ"> #child of midtop
      <form id="top_search">
        <table>
          ...
        </table>
      </form>
      <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" form="top_search">
      </p>
      <form id="mid_search">
        <table>
          ...
        </table>
      </form>
      <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" form="mid_search">
      </p> #I cannot see this button if the table is to long
    </div> #end of firstQ
  </div> #end of midtop


</div> #end of wrapper(parent)
```

[The Screenshot of my page looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3yAc.png)

I tried overflow:auto in the parent div with absolute positioning.
Doesn't really seem to work.

Thanks again!

Comment: edited. Thank you for telling me. @Pete I hope this helps.

Comment: Html comments are `<!-- comment here -->` but your problem is you have positioned the firstQ div absolutely - means it is taken out of the flow of the page and therefore adds no height to midtop (meaning it has nothing to scroll)

Comment: @Pete I do know that html comments are <!-- comment here -->. I used "#" just to make code easier to read. (At least that's the case for me. Sorry if that's bothering you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, your firstQ div cannot be absolutely positioned otherwise your midtop div will not gain any height and therefore the scroll will not work properly.

I would centre firstQ using flex and then your problem should be fixed:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: block;
}

#header {
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  left: 50%;
  top: 0%;
  display: block;
}

#midtop {
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  height: 600px;
  left: 50%;
  overflow: auto;
  
  
  display: flex;                         /* change display type */
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content:center;                /* vertical centring */
}

#firstQ {
  margin: auto;                         /* remove absolute positioning */
  width: 80%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="header"> #child1
    <p id="Welcome">Welcome!</p>
  </div> #end of header


  <div id="midtop"> #child2

    <div id="firstQ"> #child of midtop
      <form id="top_search">
        <table>
          ...
        </table>
      </form>
      <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" form="top_search">
      </p>
      <form id="mid_search">
      bob
        <table>
          ...
        </table>
      </form>
      <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" form="mid_search">
      </p> #I cannot see this button if the table is to long
    </div> #end of firstQ
  </div> #end of midtop


</div> #end of wrapper(parent)
```

Comment: I edited my css:
as for the midtop div:
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
    height: 600px;
    left: 50%;
    overflow: scroll;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    /* justify-content: center; */

And found that by adding "justify-content: center", the whole child div is shifted upwards thus making the scrollable areas smaller.

as for the firstQ div:
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;

Can I ask specifically why shouldn't i position my child div?

Comment: Then you need to make a proper [mcve] that we can work with - I can only edit the code you supply and it works in the snippet I have done

Comment: Thanks @Pete. I'll try to reproduce the scenario more precisely. Thank you for your answer! Finally solved my problem I've been thinking for some time.

Comment: Ah ok, glad you solved it.  You shouldn't accept my answer if it did not solve it - wait a couple of days and then accept your own :)

Answer (score 0):

I've edited my code and everything looked "normal" for now, but I was wondering if there is any way to simplify my code. Since I'm not really sure that the thing I wanted to do required that many lines of code.

It would be of great help if anyone could simplify this pile of code so that it could be a lot more comprehensible. I'm constantly adding and deleting parameters and I'm pretty confused by now.

```
 <div class="wrapper">

     <div class="header"> #child1
     <p id="Welcome">Welcome!</p>
     </div> #end of header


  <div id="midtop"> #child2

    <div id="firstQ"> #child of midtop
      <form id="top_search">
        <table>
          ...
        </table>
      </form>
      <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" form="top_search">
      </p>
      <form id="mid_search">
      bob
        <table>
          ...
        </table>
      </form>
      <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" form="mid_search">
      </p> #I cannot see this button if the table is to long
    </div> #end of firstQ
  </div> #end of midtop


</div> #end of wrapper(parent)


code for css:

#midtop{
margin: auto;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
height: 600px;
left: 50%;
overflow: scroll;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
/* justify-content: center; */ (Not sure why this shrinks the scrollable area)
}

#firstQ{
margin: auto;
width: 80%;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}
```